# Omitting item from array, foreach loop wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have created a foreach loop for the category section in my sidebar. Everything is working good, however, I don't want to allow one of the categories to show. I have not been able to find anything on how to null out an object in query or anything.

here is my code, the name of the category is "general information"

```
             <aside class="sidebar">
             <div class="category" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="300">
               <h2>Popular Categories</h2>
               <ul class="category-list">
              <?php
                 $args = array(
                 'orderby'  => 'count',
              'order'    => 'DESC'
             );
             $terms = get_terms('category', $args); /*Name Of category*/
              foreach (array_slice($terms, 0, 5)  as $term ):
             ?>

           
           <li class="list-items" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-delay="400">
           <a href="<?php echo site_url('/general');?>"> 
           <?php echo 
           $term->name ;?>  </a>
          <span>(<?php echo $term->count ;?>)</span>
          </li>

           <?php
          endforeach;
          wp_reset_query();
           ?>
           </ul>
        </div>
```

I am guessing that there is a call I can put in the $args(). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
   $args = array(
          'orderby'  => 'count',
          'order'    => 'DESC'
          'exclude' => array( 77 ), // ID of Category which you don't want to show
         );
```

You can exclude like this.